# Get attribute value in magento2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, attributes, product-attribute, object-manager

I am using an object manager to get the attribute value even though it's not recommended.
I am getting NULL in product-object which causing error "GetattributeText() on NULL". Below is the code that so far I tried

```
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
        $product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');
        echo gettype($product);
        $slot_break = $product->getAttributeText('choose_slot_break');
```

when I echo gettype it shows "NULLObject". I have done so much googling before posting this question and have already tried almost all the solutions in the Magento stack exchange

The above code-sniffer is working well to show the value in a PHTML but here I am trying to get this inside a function which I needed for some calculation which is in a programmatically created dropdown attribute class which extends "\Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource
". Pardon me if this ain't met the qualification to ask as a question.

Comment: please check and update me if its work.

Comment: Not sure what the context is in your case, but the problem you are facing is that the current product is not loaded in the $product variable and the call to get the attribute value fails with the error: "GetattributeText() on NULL". My best guess would be that this is either not happening on product page, or your code is getting executed before the "current_product" global variable is defined in Magento registry.

Comment: @Aashik  registry('current_product') this return an currently appear product means it's works on that page where only sigle product are see. Please check you page

Comment: I did not get like this can you show me error? also please screenshots for all

Comment: or if it is live share me url please

Comment: where you use this because if you use in any product page then it works

Answer (score 0):

please check

```
   $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
   $product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');
   echo $choose_slot_break = $product->getData('choose_slot_break');
```

hope it works.

Comment: same error "Call to a member function getData() on null in /var/www/html/magento2sample/app/code/Today/Slot/Model/Config/Source/Options.php:65"

Comment: I did not get like this can you show me error? also please screenshots for all